# NSPopover in Mac Catalyst for Mac menu bar

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui, mac-catalyst

I am trying to add a MenuBar Item to my Mac Catalyst app.

I have successfully made the iPad app work on Mac, but adding the MenuBar item is turning out to be quite difficult.

I have tried solving the issue using the following two links, but they don't have a GitHub repo which I can look at, and the explanations do some jumps.

https://www.highcaffeinecontent.com/blog/20190607-Beyond-the-Checkbox-with-Catalyst-and-AppKit
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/creating_a_mac_version_of_your_ipad_app

Right now I have the following code in my AppDelegate:

```
#if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
    import AppKit
    import Cocoa

#endif
import UIKit
import CoreData

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    
    #if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
        var popover: NSPopover!
        var statusBarItem: NSStatusItem!
    #endif

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        
        #if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
        // Code to include from Mac.
        #endif
        #if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
            let contentView = MenuBarView()

            // Create the popover
            let popover = NSPopover()
            popover.contentSize = NSSize(width: 400, height: 500)
            popover.behavior = .transient
            popover.contentViewController = NSHostingController(rootView: contentView)
            self.popover = popover
            
            // Create the status item
            self.statusBarItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: CGFloat(NSStatusItem.variableLength))
            
            if let button = self.statusBarItem.button {
                button.image = NSImage(named: "MenuBar")
                button.action = #selector(togglePopover(_:))
            }
        #endif
        
        return true
    }
    
    #if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
        @objc func togglePopover(_ sender: AnyObject?) {
             if let button = self.statusBarItem.button {
                  if self.popover.isShown {
                       self.popover.performClose(sender)
                  } else {
                       self.popover.show(relativeTo: button.bounds, of: button, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge.minY)
                        self.popover.contentViewController?.view.window?.becomeKey()
                  }
             }
        }
    #endif
    
    
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        
        guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        
        #if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
        if let titlebar = windowScene.titlebar {
            titlebar.titleVisibility = .hidden
            titlebar.toolbar = nil
        }
        #endif

    }

...more code from CoreData
```

The Errors that is is showing
[image: The Errors that is is showing]

I am really new to iOS development and I am getting really lost, so any and every help is really appreciated.

#### Edit

Yes, the screenshot is from the AppDelegate.

I am trying to implement something like this:
https://github.com/AnaghSharma/Ambar-SwiftUI

every implementation that I have seen thus far put this into the AppDelegate, which is why I am trying to do the same thing as well.

Comment: Still not officially supported, but [this dev is onto something](https://mobile.twitter.com/stroughtonsmith/status/1428882205930135556).

Comment: I actually contacted him and he helped me out

Comment: What was the solution, was it [in the example](https://github.com/steventroughtonsmith/airqualitymonitor) you mentioned in your deleted answer?

Comment: Yes, but I did not delete it, it was a mod.  Because I linked to the repo he made where the solution is posted. https://github.com/steventroughtonsmith/airqualitymonitor star it before the comment get's deleted as well

Answer (score 1):

From your screenshot, it looks like that’s the AppDelegate for your *Mac bundle*. If that’s the case, then you need to remove all the UIKit and #if TARGET_MAC_CATALYAT stuff and do everything in AppKit. That is, use NSResponder instead of UIResponder, etc.

As for sample code, this is a great start: https://github.com/noahsark769/CatalystPlayground

It includes an AppKit bundle and the code for loading it.

Comment: I edited my question and added a picture so you can see what I am trying to do. The link you sent me is a great repo, because it shows how they integrate pure mac things with catalyst.

Comment: Ah I see. That sample you linked is a pure Mac app, so it has an _ NSApplicationDelegate_ — note the NS prefix, this is AppKit not UiKit/Catalyst. 

The CatalystPlayground I linked should help you out — the Mac bundle won’t even have an app delegate because it’s not an app! As you can see in his code, you can set a “main class” for the bundle, which you then load from your UIKit code, and you can put your menubar item code in there.

Comment: PS: I don’t know if you intend to use SwiftUI, as the project you linked does, but be warned that SwiftUI and bundles don’t play well. SwiftUI Previews don’t work at all and you may run into other problems.

Comment: I am using SwiftUI because I find it more intuitive than using Storyboards. (I tried and got really stuck)

I am really sorry that I am not quite understanding this yet. The playground you linked to has a lot of things and I am a bit lost as to what I need to look for. Could you maybe point to the files that I should look at specifically. I am sorry, I am really new to iOS dev.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, it's not possible to use NSPopover in Mac Catalyst yet. From apple documentation:

> Mac apps built with Mac Catalyst can only use AppKit APIs marked as
> available in Mac Catalyst, such as NSToolbar and NSTouchBar. Mac
> Catalyst does not support accessing unavailable AppKit APIs.

And Mac Catalyst is not listed in the availability platforms list:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nspopover

Comment: At first I thought so too, but it seems that you can mix AppKit and UIKit. Example of using `NSStatusItem` in a Catalyst app: https://medium.com/geekculture/use-of-macos-specific-api-in-maccatalyst-apps-and-vice-versa-e7082a007b7c, https://twitter.com/stroughtonsmith/status/1136636794878005248, also https://github.com/mhdhejazi/Dynamic/issues/9

Comment: Some more examples: https://www.highcaffeinecontent.com/blog/20210605-Catalyst-Sample-Code-Roundup,  https://blog.overdesigned.net/posts/2021-08-26-catalyst-status-menu/, https://danielwiese.com/posts/react-native-gomobile-catalyst/

Comment: There even seems to be a library mostly with the purpose of accessing AppKit APIs in Swift from an UIKit app: https://github.com/mhdhejazi/Dynamic